# AngularJS rendering interpolation as template syntax during load

Tags: angularjs, templates, rendering, interpolation, loading

A client of mine has an issue with his AngularJS Project that during the loading, some interpolations are rendered as text before they are replaced with the proper content. I haven't encountered this behavior before. Does anyone know what they might be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: That's perfectly normal. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Note that your client isn't using Angular. It's using AngularJS.

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet - Angular was what they've told me, hadn't had the chance to look at code yet. so they just have to apply that ngCloak directive to hide slow-rendering components? Can slow async requests in the components affect the slow overall rendering time of the components ?

Comment: All you have to do is use ng-cloak in your parent tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-cloak` directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

From the Docs:

> The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading.
>
> The directive can be applied to the `<body>` element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-cloak Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)